# May i change all the <input> at the time?

Tags: javascript, html

May i know how can i batch change a input for other input at javascript
example:

```
<input type="text" id="abc">`<input type="text" id="abc1">`<input type="text" id="abc2">`

<input type="text" id="abc3">`<input type="text" id="abc4">`
```

the following abc1->abc4 will change according the 1st.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Could not understand what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: This is really easy. A little Googling will give you your answers.

Comment: @Kangkan- apparently he just wants to change the input box (abc1 - abc4) value depending on whatever value is in the first one.

Comment: rgin u a right,sry for my bad English... what i mean is there was many field to change but i just only need to change the 1st 1 <input> for make other change value same with the 1st 1. I just fix it by searching the form element..Thk for you all~

Answer (score 1):

This will get all the inputs in the document and change them to the value of the first.

```
var masterInput = document.getElementById('abc');
masterInput.onchange = function () {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i = 1; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        inputs[i].value = this.value;
    }
};
```

If you have other inputs in the page (quite likely), you can replace `document` with the parent element, or you can iterate through the `id`s individually:

```
var masterInput = document.getElementById('abc');
masterInput.onchange = function () {
    var inputs = ['abc1', 'abc2', 'abc3', 'abc4'];
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById(inputs[i]).value = this.value;
    }
};
```